# Near or Nearly, when used with 10% of

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, noun-phrases

If we consider the two sentences:

> 1. On Mondays, near 10% of the workforce report sick;
> 2. On Mondays, nearly 10% of the workforce report sick;

I am inclined to think that the latter is correct. But *'10% of the workforce'* is a noun-phrase, so the adverb *'nearly'* should not logically be there.
I saw a few sentences similar to the first, but I am not very convinced they are correct.
Couldn't find this in the Wren & Martin.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think nearly would be a better choice here - as you are describing how close percentage of sick workforce is to 10% and not describing the 10% as noun itself -

Source :

> Near or Nearly? Near can function as a verb, adverb, adjective, or
> preposition. Nearly is used as an adverb to mean "in a close manner"
> or "almost but not quite." Here are some examples that demonstrate the
> differences between various uses of near and nearly.
>
> "I'll be seeing you in the near future." Here, near describes the noun
> "future." "The cat crept near." Near is an adverb that describes where
> the cat crept. "Don't worry; we're nearly there." Here, nearly
> describes how close we are. Near can also be used as a verb and a
> preposition.
>
> "My graduation neared." Here, neared is the verb of the sentence. "I
> want the couch near the window." Near is a preposition at the head of
> the phrase "near the window."

[Owl English](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/536/02/)

Comment: Tidied up your link to demonstrate. Feel free to undo.

Comment: Thanks, Vivek. Your explanation is great. BTW, I was wondering whether the phrase '10% of the workforce' is an adjective phrase, for 'nearly' to qualify it.